# Sorting by rows with the most commonality with R

Tags: r

looking for a clever solution to this puzzle. I need to order the below data frame so that its sorted by rows with the most commonality with a value of 1 with the other rows. In sorted_df, first 4 rows have the most commonality, the next 4 have 1 in common, and the last two have none. Thanks for your help or pointing me in the right direction.

```
unsorted_df <- read.table(text="c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", header=T, sep="") 

sorted_df <- read.table(text="c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1", header=T, sep="")
```

Thanks for the comments, let me explain the sorting purpose - each row represents a person and the columns are true/false attributes. I am trying to find those that have the most overlapping/common attributes. For convenience, I want those with a lot of overlap to be at the top of the list.

Imagine cols like IsHappy, HasCar, HasPhone, etc. So there isn't a baseline, every row can have none, one, or more. I need to find rows with the most overlap and place them on top for convenience.

Comment: I don't think I follow the rules for sorting. Care to explicate some more?

Comment: I don't understand the sorting rules, as I'd like more info about the "commonality" definition. Also, is the first row the baseline? In sense that you want to compare the rest with that one in therms of that "commonality"?

Comment: I'd take a guess (not really) here and I'd say that the fact the you have column names, but you're looking for similarity (commonality) between rows shows me that you want to use it as a user similarity process based on items (like a suggestion engine). So either a) you specify an inital row and you calculate cosine similarities with all other rows, or b) for each row you calculate similarites with other rows and you get the average of them. So each row has one similarity score (avg_similarity_scores) and you rank by that.

Comment: I added additional info atop. But these are true/false attributes for a person. Imagine, IsHappy, HasCar, HasPhone, etc. So there isn't a baseline, every row can have none, one, or more. I want to find those with the most overlap with others.

Comment: My take on this question is "think `adist()`, but don't count the 0's, and we're looking for similarity, not distance"

Comment: I think part of the challenge of this question, and of many programming questions, is articulating the pattern that one initially regards as simple and intuitive. Thus, I encourage others view part of this question as asking "How do I articulate the transformation I've achieved in the following ..." The OP provided expected output, and tired to articulate the pattern/ algorithm that produced it. Of course, that's not what was actually asked ... but maybe that was a key part of the intended (?) question. Consider this when choosing to downvote.

Comment: All answers so far are great. Consider that using the maximum score maybe we favour one row extremely similar to one other against a a group of other rows that are somehow similar. My point is if we create pairwise scores then each row has a distribution of scores. You can use maximum, average, median, etc and see what fits what you have in mind.

Comment: @AntoniosK Good point there! I bet that this is a specific case of a more generic statistical method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I get what the OP is after. Compare each possible pair of rows, and call a given pair `R1` and `R2`, if you do `sum(R1*R2)`, use that sum of element-wise products to define a score for both rows involved in that pair. Then each row is given a top score according to the maximum of the scores from all pairs. Then sort the rows by their maximum score.

This winds up still being arbitrary when there are ties.

Here is my solution that is probably not ideal, but it was created while trying to work out what the OP meant, so please note that.

```
unsorted_df <- read.table(text="c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0", header=T, sep="")



N <- nrow(unsorted_df)
same1 <- function(x,y) sum((x+y)==2, na.rm=TRUE)
df_list <- unlist(apply(unsorted_df, 1, list),F,F)
df_combos <- which(upper.tri(matrix(NA, nrow=N, ncol=N)),arr.ind=T) #expand.grid(1:length(df_list),1:length(df_list))
commonality <- mapply(same1, df_list[df_combos[,1]], df_list[df_combos[,2]])
best_match <- c()
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
    best_match[i] <- max(commonality[apply(df_combos,1,function(x)i%in%x)])
}

unsorted_df[order(best_match, decreasing=TRUE),]

   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
1   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0
3   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
4   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0
9   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0
5   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
6   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
7   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0   0   0
8   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   1
10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thanks rbatt, this is the exact output I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
sorted_df <- unsorted_df
for (i in 1:(nrow(sorted_df)-1)){
  similarity <- which.max(sapply((i+1):nrow(sorted_df),function(x) sum(sorted_df[x,]*sorted_df[i,])))
  temp <- sorted_df[i+1,]
  sorted_df[i+1,] <- sorted_df[i+similarity,]
  sorted_df[i+similarity,] <- temp
}
#> sorted_df
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12
#1   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0
#2   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
#3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   1
#4   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0
#5   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0
#6   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
#7   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0   0   0
#8   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
#9   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0
#10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```

The degree of similarity of different rows is calculated by the sum of their product (an inner product, in mathematical terms). The sorting starts with the first row, which remains unchanged. Then, the next similar row is attached below and the the row that has been replaced is stored at the position of the row that is used for the replacement.

The final result is not unambiguous because it can happen that a row has no similarity with any other row that has not yet been sorted. This happens, e.g., in row2 and explains seemingly different results.

Comment: Good point about the inner product, that's more efficient than my `same1` function (I should just multiply then sum, not element-wise addition then test for ==2 then sum); however, I don't think your output is correct. Your 3rd row has no 1's in common, but rows `4:9` all have at least 1 in common with another row.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @rbatt . I see your point but I don't think I agree. It may be a matter of how the problem is stated that gives rises to ambiguities. I'm not trying to sort by similarities in absolute terms, but as a sequence. The third row in my output is just as different from row 2 as the third row in your output. My sorting is done in the sense of a "Markov chain".

Comment: @rbatt After reconsideration, I realized that in the OP it is in fact stated that an absolute order is desired, so I think that your solution is better. I'll try to see if I can improve mine.

Comment: thanks RHertel, you are correct, it isn't the exact output I needed but appreciate your help and explanations. I up'd arrow on both of your solutions.

Comment: @RHertel Oh, cool – I see what you mean about the sequential distances. I could see myself looking back to your answer for a future question!

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party again, but I believe in retaining data you worked so hard to get.
For example: why not retain the commonality information.

```
unsorted_df$commonality <- colSums(sapply(1:nrow(unsorted_df), function(y){
                                   sapply(1:ncol(unsorted_df), function(x){ 
                           colSums(unsorted_df)[x] > 1 & unsorted_df[y,x]})}))
unsorted_df
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 commonality
#1   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0           3
#2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   1           0
#3   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0           2
#4   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0           2
#5   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0           1
#6   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0           1
#7   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0   0   0           1
#8   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0           1
#9   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0           2
#10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0           0

(sorted_df <- unsorted_df[order(unsorted_df[,"commonality"], decreasing=TRUE),])
#   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 commonality
#1   1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0           3
#3   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0           2
#4   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0           2
#9   0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0   0   0   0           2
#5   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0           1
#6   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0           1
#7   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0   0   0           1
#8   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   0           1
#2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   1           0
#10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0           0
```

**Explanation**

For every row, `y`, go through each column, `x`,  and if the sum of that column is greater than 1 AND the value at that point is not `0`, `NA`, `NULL`, or `FALSE`, fill a new matrix and define that point as `TRUE`, all other points are `FALSE`.

This creates a transposed matrix of `TRUE`/`FALSE` entries.

The sum of the columns (`TRUE`=1, `FALSE`=0) of this new matrix is the `commonality` value for each row.

Comment: Very slick, clean solution indeed.

Comment: Yes, N8TRO, nice indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it using dplyr.
Run the chained commands step by step to check the output after every step.
You might be able to improve it.

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(x1=c(1,1,0,0),
                x2=c(1,1,1,1),
                x3=c(0,1,0,1))
```

Looks like this and we work with rows

```
 x1 x2 x3
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  1
3  0  1  0
4  0  1  1
```

Then we do

```
# give an id to each user (row)
dt = dt %>% mutate(id=row_number())

expand.grid(dt$id,dt$id) %>% # create all combinations of user ids
  data.frame() %>% 
  filter(Var1 != Var2) %>% # exclude users paired with themseves
  left_join(dt, by=c("Var1"="id")) %>% # join actual rows
  left_join(dt, by=c("Var2"="id")) %>% # join actual rows
  select(-Var1,-Var2) %>% # remove ids
  group_by(x1.x, x2.x, x3.x, x1.y, x2.y, x3.y) %>% # group by combination of users' rows
  do(data.frame(score=sum(.[1:3]*.[4:6])/sqrt(sum(.[1:3]^2)*sum(.[4:6]^2)))) %>% # create cosine similarity per row
  group_by(x1.x, x2.x, x3.x) %>% # group per user's row
  summarise(MeanScore = mean(score),
            MaxScore = max(score),
            MedianScore = median(score)) %>%
  ungroup
```

The final output provides summary stats for the score distribution for each row (user) which you can use to rank

```
  x1.x x2.x x3.x MeanScore  MaxScore MedianScore
1    0    1    0 0.6638546 0.7071068   0.7071068
2    0    1    1 0.6745345 0.8164966   0.7071068
3    1    1    0 0.6745345 0.8164966   0.7071068
4    1    1    1 0.7367811 0.8164966   0.8164966
```

No need for for-loops using dplyr.
There's some more work to do inside the "do" command to automate the process, but it's easy if you use the number of users (rows) of your initial dataset.